# How open dialog primefaces on top page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I tired open dialag on top page.
I add flag `position` in map propertis set to `top` but not work.

primefaces 6.0

Dialog visible in center.

```
public void openWindowNotification() {
        try {
            System.err.println("openWindowNotification");
            Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            options.put("draggable", false);
            options.put("modal", true);
            options.put("position", "top"); // <--- not work
            options.put("width", "90%");
            options.put("contentWidth", "90%");
            options.put("height", "90%");
            options.put("contentheight", "90%");
            options.put("size", "auto");
            options.put("widgetVar", "editarDialog");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("window/WindowNotification", options, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas ?

edit:
fire bug show code:

```
> <div id="formFindPanel:bAdd_dlg" class="ui-dialog ui-widget
> ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-hidden-container
> ui-resizable ui-overlay-visible"
> data-widgetvar="formFindPanel_bAdd_dlgwidget"
> data-pfdlgcid="96e9d80e-f114-49a2-8699-1684bf9e3418" style="width:
> 90%; height: auto; left: 83px; top: 365.5px; visibility: visible;
> z-index: 1001; display: block;" role="dialog"
> aria-labelledby="formFindPanel:bAdd_dlg_title" aria-hidden="false"
> aria-live="polite">
```

in css is `top` propertis `365.5px` what causes that dialog is in center.

I need set to top around ~15px;

Comment: @YagamiLight: A growl as a replacement for a dialog from the PF dialog Framework???

Comment: Please always post version info. But in this case it is kind of irrelevant. There is no 'position' configuration option in 5.3 and 6.0. Maybe you can look at the generated html and try some css on the iframe that contains the dialog page

Comment: i not wont growl, my window is standard dialog/window have input controls and button submit

Comment: Is it might possible to set something like... `position:absolute; top: 80%;` as further attributes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932671/primefaces-dialogframework-top-positioning

Answer (score 1):

You can just set a hard value (e.g 500) to the height, it should work.

Comment: @MrLY: looks like an answer to me, albeit a short one.