# PrimeFaces DialogFramework top positioning

Tags: primefaces

I use PrimeFaces 6 and want to position the dialog on top:

`options.put("position", "top");`

However this does not work. Is there any way to center the dialog on top?

I am quite desperate now

Answer (score 1):

**As per Primefaces User Guide 6.0**

**Position**

By default dialog is positioned at center of the viewport and position option is used to change the
location of the dialog. Possible values are;

• Single string value like *‘center’, ‘left’, ‘right’, ‘top’, ‘bottom’* representing the position within
viewport.

• Comma separated x and y coordinate values like 200, 500

• Comma separated position values like *‘top’,‘right’*. (Use single quotes when using a combination)

*Some examples are described below;*

```
<p:dialog position="top" ...>

<p:dialog position="left,top" ...>

<p:dialog position="200,50" ...>
```

Comment: However this does not work using Dialog Framework ;(

Comment: i see. Yes. from the full list of configuration options for dialog framework three is no position there. Have you tried doing css for this?

Comment: The "position" attribute has been added by me in PF 6.2 for the DialogFramework so this is viable now.

Answer (score 0):

I know, you would like to set position to **primefaces external dialog(dialog framework)**.
You cannot `style or css` to dialog because which is wrap by `ifram`.

But, it is OK to apply `css` to generated `div`. This `div` id is `formId + commendLinkId or commendButtonId + _dlg`

Example

```
<h:form id="myForm">

    <p:commandButton id="myDialgoBtm" value="Select" action="...." immediate="true">
        <p:ajax ..../>
    </p:commandButton>  

</h:form>
```

Client/Brower Source

```
<div id="myForm:myDialogBtn_dlg" ..>
    <div ....>
        //this is bor title bar of dialog
    </div>
    <div ....>
        //this is bor content of dialog
        <ifarm ....>
            //here your external dialog page                
        </ifarm>
    </div>
</div>
```

if so, the `id` of `div` will be `myForm:myDialogBtn_dlg`. You can inspect in browser.

Example CSS for your dialog

```
#myForm\:myDialogBtn_dlg {
    top: 0px!important
}
```

I don't think, it will be better solution, Currently, I solve this issue by above way.

Comment: The easier way is using the "position" attribute described below.  It works for regular dialogs and DialogFramework as of PF 6.2

Answer (score 0):

I was finding the solution, but the only way that I found it was this:

> .ui-dialog {
>              top: 100px !important;
>           }

I put this code below of

Comment: below of what ?

Answer (score 0):

I simply created a new (div id="dialog") then placed it at the top of my template. I then also placed the buttons invoking the dialog to show at the top of the pages (ui:define) Lastly, I updated the dialog to appendTo="@(dialog)"